# A neurologist or a psychiatrist or a psychologist, who is better suited to diagnose neurodevelopmental disorders?

Tags: neurology, psychologist-psychology, psychiatrist-psychiatry, development-disorder

There are a lot of neurodevelopmental conditions which are hidden-type and resembles mental conditions. These includes sensory processing disorders, prosopagnosia, developmental coordination disorder (dyspraxia), ADHD, autism, dyslexia, dyscalculia etc.

Which speciality is better suited to diagnose these type of conditions?  A neurologist or a psychologist or a psychiatrist?

Comment: Have you considered the limits of their training and licensure? Psychologists, for example, aren't medical doctors, so they can't diagnose physical or drug-induced disorders.

Comment: There is a specialty called [Neuropsychiatry](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3653233/); basically it deals with "mental disorders" (not my choice of words) that have a neurological component. (N.B. The official stance is that the brain and mind are not separate entities but are integrated. While that might be obvious to some, it's unlike psychiatry, which takes a dualistic approach: think Freud.) They may be harder to find, though.